# How to prevent search engines indexing a specific url

Tags: search, url, indexing, robots.txt

I have a url which i don't want indexed:

```
http://www.mysite.com/moduleA?param=secretkey
```

So when i google search for "mysite.com", i don't want the above link to appear in the search results.

However, the following urls are part of public viewing:

```
www.mysite.com/moduleA
www.mysite.com/moduleA?id=12345
www.mysite.com/moduleA/somepage.html
```

Can this be done? Can robots file be used for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things you can do:

- [Block that URL in a `robots.txt` file.](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449)
- [Output a `ROBOTS` `META` tag in the header when that param is included.](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=93710)

Ultimately, though, nothing secret should ever go directly in a URL like that - not all web crawlers obey these robots instructions, and some (spambots etc.) specifically search them out and look at them.

Comment: Right! Basically, the hidden link is like a preview content before being posted for public viewing (or deleted). Theres no secret or personal data being hidden there. So i thought of this approach to avoid code duplication. You think its fine in this case?